# Getting error "you must have a tty to run sudo" when we run through Pentaho

Tags: r, shell, sudo, pentaho-spoon

I am getting a `you must have a tty to run sudo` error when I run a shell script with a R script in it.

Weird thing is, it doesn't happen every time. I think it is because of RAM issue, but I am not sure.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: A now-deleted answer linked [to this resource](//unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password).

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are running on a Linux distribution with 'sudo' configured to require a *tty*.

Please refer this link for an easy fix:
https://www.shell-tips.com/2014/09/08/sudo-sorry-you-must-have-a-tty-to-run-sudo/

Comment: Your other answer was deleted for being link-only. I've not reported this one as it has some detail in it, but not much. Can you expand on it at all? May we see the fix itself in the post?

Comment: Its resolved now. I have kept sudo word inside shell script , that's why it was failing with above error. After removing sudo inside the shell script, it is working fine.